# Apache Kafka - list only specific consumer groups

Tags: apache-kafka, authorization, acl

is there any way to control user authorization for listing consumer groups in Apache Kafka?
There is Read and Describe permission, however user can list all consumer groups.
I tried to set prefixed permissions for specific user to be authorized only for specific groups (Create, Read, Describe, Write), however they can list all groups.
When I use Kafka-UI, user lists all groups and try to describe group by group. For those, where no Describe permission is allowed Kafka-UI fails.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're talking about [RBAC](https://www.digitalguardian.com/blog/what-role-based-access-control-rbac-examples-benefits-and-more), or role-based access control.

Here's the [documentation](https://provectus.gitbook.io/kafka-ui/configuration/rbac-role-based-access-control) on how to implement that with Kafka UI.

Comment: No, we use ACLs (Access Control Lists) per user, what fits our needs for now. Permissions are set with kafka-acls command. It is possible to list  specific topic if there is READ or DESCRIBE permission. Howeever, user can list consumer groups even if there is no READ or DESCRIBE permission. I need reduce possibility of listing specific consumer groups for specific users.